# Kill vector of processes in parallel in Tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I have a vec of processes and I would like to kill them all in parallel.

I was trying something like:

```
use futures::future;

async kill_all(processes: Vec<tokio::process::Child>) {
    let mut deaths = processes.iter_mut().map(|&mut p| p.kill());
    future::join_all(deaths).await;
}
```

But that obviously doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a more complete [MRE]. What type is `processes`? How do you spawn your processes? Are we inside of an `async` function? Please provide a full example including `use` statements and a `main` function.